# Как запустить бесконечный цикл в программе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, многопоточность, pyqt5

Делаю программу - лаунчер для игры. Работаю частично в Qt Deisgner и в редакторе. Есть Label, который выводит статус и кол. игроков на двух серверах.

```
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import time
        import webbrowser
    
    
        URLServerOne = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10846961"
        ResponseServerOne = requests.get(URLServerOne)
        SoupServerOne = BeautifulSoup(ResponseServerOne.content, 'html.parser')
        PlayerStatusServerOne = SoupServerOne.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
        PlayerCountServerOne = SoupServerOne.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text
    
        URLServerTwo = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10648280"
        ResponseServerTwo = requests.get(URLServerTwo)
        SoupServerTwo = BeautifulSoup(ResponseServerTwo.content, 'html.parser')
        PlayerStatusServerTwo = SoupServerTwo.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
        PlayerCountServerTwo = SoupServerTwo.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text
    
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус серверов: Valheim.by #1 - {0} - {1}\nValheim.by #2 - {2} - {3}".format(PlayerStatusServerOne, PlayerCountServerOne, PlayerStatusServerTwo, PlayerCountServerTwo)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Хочу сделать бесконечный цикл, который каждые 15 минут будет обновлять счётчик онлайн на сервере:

```
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import time
        import webbrowser
        import threading

        while True:
                URLServerOne = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10846961"
                ResponseServerOne = requests.get(URLServerOne)
                SoupServerOne = BeautifulSoup(ResponseServerOne.content, 'html.parser')
                PlayerStatusServerOne = SoupServerOne.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
                PlayerCountServerOne = SoupServerOne.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text

                URLServerTwo = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10648280"
                ResponseServerTwo = requests.get(URLServerTwo)
                SoupServerTwo = BeautifulSoup(ResponseServerTwo.content, 'html.parser')
                PlayerStatusServerTwo = SoupServerTwo.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
                PlayerCountServerTwo = SoupServerTwo.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text

                if PlayerStatusServerOne == "online":
                        PlayerStatusServerOne = "Онлайн"
                if PlayerStatusServerOne == "offline":
                        PlayerStatusServerOne = "Оффлайн"

                if PlayerStatusServerTwo == "online":
                        PlayerStatusServerTwo = "Онлайн"
                if PlayerStatusServerTwo == "offline":
                        PlayerStatusServerTwo = "Оффлайн"

                #print('25')
                time.sleep(1)

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Valheim.by - Launcher"))
        self.progressBar.setFormat(_translate("MainWindow", "%p%"))
        self.commandLinkButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Valheim.by - наш сайт"))
        self.commandLinkButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Discord сервер"))
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://valheim.by'))
        self.commandLinkButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://discord.gg/XCA6bPp3qB'))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "В ИГРУ"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус серверов: Valheim.by #1 - {0} - {1}\nValheim.by #2 - {2} - {3}".format(PlayerStatusServerOne, PlayerCountServerOne, PlayerStatusServerTwo, PlayerCountServerTwo)))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Статус загрузки:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Проверка завершена"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    t = threading.Thread(target=retranslateUi, args=())
    t.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но программа не запускается, а в консоль `print()` выводит, то есть считай цикл работает.

Comment: Лучше отделить код гуи от кода потока, т.к. они к разным потокам относятся. А состояния из потока передавать через сигналы. Поток лучше создавать Qt'шный, т.е. от `QThread`. Накидаю пример в ответе

Comment: while True и time.sleep - сразу напрашивается таймер. изза requests в коде его конечно прийдется перенести в тред.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Накидал пример реализации класса потока для запуска в нем тяжелых операций и как можно связать его к GUI. И сделал рефакторинг названий переменных, чтобы они соответствовали PEP

*Вообще, можно сделать универсальный класс потока. Текущий использует всю логику из вашего кода, но можно сделать так, чтобы URL к сайту передавался в конструкторе потока, тогда для каждого сервера нужно будет сделать свой объект потока (покажу пример ниже в **PS.**). Либо на класс потока передавать список адресов, а тот будет ходить по ним и по сигналу передавать адрес сайта и статус*

Вам нужно будет создать объект потока, навесить его сигнал(ы) на методы, в которые будет значение передаваться и запустить поток.

Пример:

```
import time
import sys
import webbrowser

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal


class CheckServerStatusThread(QThread):
    about_status1 = pyqtSignal(str)
    about_status2 = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, timeout=15 * 50):
        super().__init__()

        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.about_status1.emit('<Выполняю запрос к серверу>')

            url_server_one = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10846961"
            rs = requests.get(url_server_one)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
            player_status_server_one = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
            player_count_server_one = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text

            self.about_status2.emit('<Выполняю запрос к серверу>')

            url_server_two = "https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10648280"
            rs = requests.get(url_server_two)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
            player_status_server_two = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
            player_count_server_two = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text

            if player_status_server_one == "online":
                player_status_server_one = "Онлайн"
            elif player_status_server_one == "offline":
                player_status_server_one = "Оффлайн"

            if player_status_server_two == "online":
                player_status_server_two = "Онлайн"
            elif player_status_server_two == "offline":
                player_status_server_two = "Оффлайн"

            self.about_status1.emit(player_status_server_one)
            self.about_status2.emit(player_status_server_two)

            time.sleep(self.timeout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.thread = CheckServerStatusThread()
        self.thread.about_status1.connect(self.label.setText)
        # Для второго аналогично указать своего получателя:
        # self.thread.about_status2.connect(self.label.setText)
        self.thread.start()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Работа выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И через несколько секунд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Возможно, серверов на проверку будет становиться больше и чтобы не менять логику класса потока, можно его завязать на работу только с одним адресом, для двух и более адресов нужно будет только создать свои объекты-потоки:

```
class CheckServerStatusThread(QThread):
    about_status = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url: str,  timeout=15 * 50):
        super().__init__()

        self.url = url
        self.timeout = timeout

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.about_status.emit('<Выполняю запрос к серверу>')

            rs = requests.get(self.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
            player_status = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(8)').text
            # player_count = soup.select_one('.dl-horizontal :nth-child(4)').text

            if player_status == "online":
                player_status = "Онлайн"
            elif player_status == "offline":
                player_status = "Оффлайн"

            self.about_status.emit(player_status)

            time.sleep(self.timeout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel()

        self.thread = CheckServerStatusThread("https://www.battlemetrics.com/servers/valheim/10846961")
        self.thread.about_status.connect(self.label.setText)
        self.thread.start()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
```

Comment: Но как мне добавить это всё в своё окно? Не создавая новый класс.
https://prnt.sc/1102n7n .. https://pastebin.com/ic5zzbPt

Уже минут 15 потею, не могу сообразить.

Comment: @hoojpop, пожалуйста: https://pastebin.com/4SeThfHP Кст, советую использовать компоновщики (layout, типа QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, ...) они доступны и в дизайнере и их главная плюшка -- виджеты автоматически размещаются и автоматически меняют размер, т.е. нет нужны в ручной подгонке. Сейчас у вас если окно уменьшить или увеличить, то или виджеты будут скрыты за границей окна, или появятся некрасивые пустые места, а с компоновщиками это будет просто решено :) И еще лучше не менять Ui_MainWindow, а логику добавлять в свой виджет, как это сделал в ссылке

Comment: Спасибо тут мало! Помню Вас, не первый раз меня выручаете.

Comment: @hoojpop, пожалуйста ;)